# print call in python 3.4

Tags: python, printing

Hi I'm teaching myself python, have downloaded 3.4 and am working through Think Python. The problem i'm having is printing a grid. I won't put the whole code up but the bit that is a problem.

```
def do_twice(f):  
    f()  
    f()

def print_beam():   
    print("+ - - - - ", )

def print_beams():  
    do_twice(print_beam)
    print("+")
```

now this when called is supposed to print a beam like this + - - - - + - - - - +

However, the actual output is
+ - - - -
+ - - - -
+

I've spent a good two hours on this but the version of python i'm using is different from the book I'm working on. Could anyone help me out of this log jam?

Comment: What version are you using? If you aren't sure, try `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: You're reading a Python 2 tutorial and running it on Python 3. That's the problem.

Comment: 3.4.4 but the book is something diff 3.2 maybe

Comment: If your book suggested putting a comma at the end of a `print` statement in order to suppress a newline, then it's almost certainly written for 2.7 or lower. I assume that's why you've got a stray comma in your `print_beam` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, the `print` function creates a new line at the end of its output. Here's an easy fix.

```
def do_twice(f):  
    f()  
    f()

def print_beam():   
    print("+ - - - - ", end='') #Don't create a new line.

def print_beams():  
    do_twice(print_beam)
    print("+")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gareth, that has fixed it immediately. So glad I came here instead of banging my head for another 2 hours. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MarkNolan Don't forget to mark this as the answer for others passing by!

Answer (score 1):

With python 3 to prevent newline characters being printed set `end=""` like so:

`print("+ - - - -", end="")`

You can read the documentation on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 0):

print statements with argument (end), lets you continue on the next line.
i used python 3.8 version

```
def print_beam():
    print('+',end=' ')
    print('-','-','-','-', end=' ')
    print('+', end=' ')
    print('-', '-', '-', '-', end=' ')
    print('+')

def print_column():
    print('|',end=' ')
    print(' ',' ',' ',' ', end=' ')
    print('|', end=' ')
    print(' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', end=' ')
    print('|')
```

Comment: This does not answer his question